# Glassfish and Java EE Webapp 500 error 4 out of 5 times

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I am trying to make a REST service with Glassfish 4.  I have a SOAP service and Servlet working properly, but cannot get the REST stuff to work.

Here is my simple DAO:

```
@Remote
@WebService
public interface IPersonDao {

    public void createAndSave(String fn, String ln, String eid);
    public void persist(Person p);
    public Collection<Person> getAllPeople();
    public Person getPerson(Integer id);
    public void delete(Person p);
    public void deleteById(Integer id);
}




@Stateless
@Remote(IPersonDao.class)
@Named("MemoryPersonDao")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "dummy.server.IPersonDao")
public class PersonDao implements IPersonDao {
    Map<Integer, Person> people;
    int id_seq = 1;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public PersonDao() {
        people = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, Person>();
        /*createAndSave("Mike", "Jones", "2234");
        createAndSave("Joe", "Smith", "22314");*/
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        createAndSave("Mike", "Jones", "2234");
        createAndSave("Joe", "Smith", "22314");
    }

    private int nextId() {
        return id_seq++;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see dummy.server.IPersonDao#createAndSave(java.lang.String,
     * java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void createAndSave(String fn, String ln, String eid) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName(fn);
        p.setLastName(ln);
        p.setEmployeeId(eid);
        p.setId(nextId());
        persist(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPerson(Integer id) {
        return people.get(id);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see dummy.server.IPersonDao#persist(dummy.server.Person)
     */
    @Override
    public void persist(Person p) {
        if (p.getId() != null) {
            p.setId(nextId());
        }
        people.put(p.getId(), p);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see dummy.server.IPersonDao#getAllPeople()
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<Person> getAllPeople() {
        return people.values();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see dummy.server.IPersonDao#delete(dummy.server.Person)
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Person p) {
        deleteById(p.getId());
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see dummy.server.IPersonDao#deleteById(java.lang.Integer)
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        people.remove(id);
    }
```

Here's my REST class

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class PersonRestService extends Application {
    @EJB
    IPersonDao personDao;

    /**
     * 
     */

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(PersonRestService.class);
        return classes;
    }

    public PersonRestService() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("people")
    public String test() {
        return "TEST OK";
    }

    public Collection<Person> getPeople(){
        System.err.println("Getting all people!");
        return personDao.getAllPeople();
    }
}
```

I also have a servlet that works and a SOAP service that works (I can see the ?wsdl and the ?Tester pages).  What is my REST URL?  I see this in the log:

`2015-07-07T10:17:32.052-0400|Info: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named dummy.server.PersonRestService, at the servlet mapping /api/*, with the Application class of the same name.`

Here is my web.xml (not needed due to using annotations):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>GB</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is my glassfish-web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/GB</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

However, I cannot figure out my REST URL.  Anybody know what gives here?

Comment: Put your rest endpoint in a different class annotated with `@Path` and make it `@Stateless` in order to inject your EJB. See what happens

Comment: I did that, and no difference.  I separated the `PersonRestService` (annotated with @Path) and left the class that `extends Application` with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation and the `getClasses()` method.